# How to add a onclick event to an element generated automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to generate a table dynamically with elements I am getting through a fetch, I get to draw the table with the users, but I would like to add a onclick function to each one of the rows so whenever I click on the row I get the books attached to that user(which are gotten from the database), anyways my question is how can I add a function to each tr each time a tr is generated so when I click on a tr I call a function. I tried to add an eventlistener on the `drawUsersTable function` to each tr but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code:

```html
  <body>
    <script>
      async function getToken() {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/auth", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            user: "jesus",
            password: "1234"
          })
        });
        const { token } = await response.json(); //esta linea no se ejecutara hasta que response este resuelta
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      }

      async function printUsers() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        });
        const users = await response.json();
        drawUsersTable(users);
      }

      const drawUsersTable = users => {
        cont = 1;
        const table = document.getElementById("table");
        users.forEach(({ user_id, username, isAdmin }) => {
          
          const firstTD = document.createElement("td");          
          const secondTD = document.createElement("td");
          const thirdTD = document.createElement("td");

          firstTD.innerText = user_id;
          secondTD.innerText = username;
          thirdTD.innerText = isAdmin;

          const tr = document.createElement("tr");
          tr.setAttribute("id", "user_id" + cont);
          tr.addEventListener("click", printBooks(user_id));
          cont = cont + 1;
          tr.append(firstTD, secondTD, thirdTD);
          table.append(tr);
        });
      };
      getToken().then(() => printUsers());

      async function printBooks(userId) {    
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");        
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/bookUser/:userId/books", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        });
        const books = await response.json();
        console.log(books);
      }


    </script>

    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td class="id">ID</td>
        <td>Username</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried this but it is not working, instead of adding the onclick method to each row, it prints out all the code on the screen....  any hints?

```html
const drawUsersTable = users => {
        cont = 1;
        const table = document.getElementById("table");
        users.forEach(({ user_id, username, isAdmin }) => {
          const firstTD = document.createElement("td");
          const secondTD = document.createElement("td");
          const thirdTD = document.createElement("td");

          firstTD.innerText = user_id;
          secondTD.innerText = username;
          thirdTD.innerText = isAdmin;

          const tr = document.createElement("tr");
          tr.setAttribute("id", "user_id" + cont);
          tr.onclick =  function(user_id){
            const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            const response =  fetch("http://localhost:3000/bookUser/:userId/books", {
              headers: {
               Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
            });
            const books =  response.json();
            console.log(books);
          }
```

Comment: This might have been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Comment: Thanks, I have checked it already but that is Jquery I would like JS solution  if possible

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
const tr = document.createElement("tr");
```

Can you not add:

```
tr.onclick = function() { alert('magic'); };
```

Comment: tr.onclick = printBooks(user_id)

Answer (score 0):

`element.onclick = functionName()`  should work.

**Check the code here**

https://jsfiddle.net/Arpit09/dbxzuyre/17/

Comment: Thanks but I already  tried adding elemnt.onclick and it did not add any function to the tr... dont know what I am missing...

Comment: @jesusfernandez please check the jsfiddler link with the answer

Comment: that seems like something I can use I will try later and let you know if it works for my code, thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: still not working I dunno why it does not add any function to my tr...